# Assign instances of classes in master class and preserve context of child class instance

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a master class in my app and inside it's initialization routine `this.init()` i'm trying to assign some other instances of other classes to the master class but the context changes and I'm not sure how can I avoid this

```
function Models(settings) {

    Object.defineProperty(this, "active", {
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: false,
        writable: true,
        value: undefined
    });

    if (!(this instanceof Models)) {
        return new Models(settings);
    } else {
        return this;
    }

}

Object.defineProperties(Models.prototype, {

    constructor: Models,

    load: {
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: false,
        writable: false,
        value: function(id) {

            console.log(id, this, typeof id, this.hasOwnProperty(id));

            if (typeof id !== typeof undefined && this.hasOwnProperty(id)) {

                for (var i = 0, len = this[id].length; i < len; i++) {
                    this[id][i].emit("show");
                }

                this.active = id;

            }

            return this;

        }
    },

    unload: {
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: false,
        writable: false,
        value: function(id) {

            if (typeof id !== typeof undefined && this.hasOwnProperty(id)) {

                for (var i = 0, len = this[id]; i < len; i++) {
                    this[id][i].emit("hide");
                }

            }

            if (id === this.active) {
                this.active = undefined;
            }

            return this;

        }
    },

    loadOnly: {

        configurable: false,
        enumerable: false,
        writable: false,
        value: function(id) {
            this.unload(this.active).load(id);
        }

    }

});

this.models = new Models();

this.on("models.load", this.models.load);

this.on("models.unload", this.models.unload);

this.on("models.loadOnly", this.models.loadOnly);
```

This is the code inside my init function. The problem is that after the assigment `this.models = new Models()` this.models is refering still to the master class instead of the new created Models instance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with eventEmitter the event handlers were chanign the context of the Models prototypes.

I solved it by doing this:

```
this.on("models.load", this.models.load.bind(this.models));
this.on("models.unload", this.models.unload.bind(this.models));
this.on("models.loadOnly", this.models.loadOnly.bind(this.models));
```